# How do I access a server on localhost with nginx docker container?

Tags: node.js, nginx, docker

I'm trying to use a dockerized version of nginx as a proxy server for my node (ExpressJS) application. Without any configuration to nginx and publishing port 80 for the container, I am able to see the default nginx landing page. So I know that much is working.

Now I can mount my sites-enabled directory that contains the configuration for `proxy_pass localhost:3000`. I have my node application running locally (not in any Docker container) and I can access it via port 3000 (i.e. `localhost:3000`). However, I would assume that with nginx container running, mapped to port 80, and proxying my localhost:3000, that I would be able to see my *very* simple (hello world) application. Instead I receive a 502.

Do I need to pass something into docker? Is this likely a nginx configuration error? Here is my nginx configuration:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  }
}
```

I have tried using [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach?rq=1) but it did not seem to help. That is unless I'm doing something completely wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Local MySQL Server Through Docker?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27556301/connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-docker)

Comment: I tried that as well and couldn't seem to get it to work. I know this similar question has been asked many times and even the 502 error I'm getting has been too, but none of those have worked. I will re-check when I am home from work.

Comment: DNS ftw, imo.  The host has a name ;)

Comment: docker on linux, version >= `20.04` can use `host.docker.internal` with a run flag; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61424570/2014893

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can get your current IP address as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845694/how-do-i-find-my-computers-ip-address-using-the-bash-shell):

```
ifconfig en0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print $2}'
```

Then you can use the `--add-host` flag with `docker run`:

```
docker run --add-host localnode:$(ifconfig en0 | grep inet | grep -v inet6 | awk '{print \$2}') ...
```

In your `proxypass` use `localnode` instead of `localhost`.

Comment: This was along the right lines but did not work exactly for me. For one I am working off my laptop so my method of extracting the ip was obviously different. I tried using the same method changing `en0` but kept getting results with `addr:192.xxx.x.xx` so I eventually just hard-coded that in. What utility would I use to strip the beginning `addr:` as providing that will not work with docker. Thank you though. I'm writing this comment for others who come across this problem.

Comment: Nevermind, I used `sed` in order to strip the beginning `addr:`. As you can tell I'm not a sysops guy :)

Comment: Awesome suggestion. Thanks, mate.

Comment: On my Ubuntu, it's eth0 instead of en0.

Answer (score 78):

If you're using docker-for-mac 18.03 or newer it auto creates a special DNS entry `host.docker.internal` that dynamically binds to the host inet ip. You can then use the dns name to proxy services running on the host machine from inside a container as a stand-in for `localhost`.

i.e. an nginx config file:

```
server {
  listen 0.0.0.0:80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://host.docker.internal:3000;
  }
}
```

Comment: I used this solution! Thanks easy and simple

Comment: Note: `host.docker.internal` does not work on linux.

Comment: Unless you set `extra-hosts` https://stackoverflow.com/a/43541732/6790541

Comment: This also worked for me on a Windows 10 host.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Docker needs to know about your host machine. You can set an alias to that with the `--add-host` switch. On a *nix box to create an alias to a name "localbox", this would be:

```
docker run my_repo/my_image --add-host=localbox:<host_name>`
```

On boot2docker it would be:

```
docker run my_repo/my_image --add-host=localbox:192.168.59.3`
```

where you should replace "192.168.59.3" with whatever `boot2docker ip` returns.

Then, you should access your host machine always through the alias localbox, so just change your nginx config to:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://localbox:3000;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

On linux, this works for me:

In the docker-compose.yml, mount an entrypoint script into the nginx container:

```yml
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.19.2
    # ...
    volumes:
      - ./nginx-entrypoint.sh:/docker-entrypoint.d/nginx-entrypoint.sh:ro
```

The contents of the entrypoint map a local address to the host local address.

```sh
apt update
apt install iproute2 -y
echo "`ip route | awk '/default/ { print $3 }'`\tdocker.host.internal" >> /etc/hosts
```

Then, instead of using `localhost` inside the container, you can use `docker.host.internal`.

Answer (score -2):

And finally, if you are using Nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple services, you can spin all of that with docker-compose. Make sure to expose ports “80:80” only on the Nginx service. Other services you can expose only the service port without mapping to the underlying network like so:

```
web:
.....
    expose:
       - 8080
nginx:
.....
    port:
        - “80:80”
```

and then use Nginx configuration proxy_pass http://service-name:port
You don’t need the upstream app part at all

Comment: It's not clear what you mean here by "upstream app part" that we won't need.  Also this ends up being not very portable if ```http://service-name``` is your external domain instead of localhost.  That was the first alternative I found to localhost, but I don't like it because I can't be sure that my nginx redirects aren't in fact going back out to the internet just to come in on a different port.

Comment: Please read the docs, it’s a technical term that you should be familiar with. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html

Comment: It is a technical term I was familiar with, but I wouldn't expect everyone to be, nor was I even sure that's what you were referring to.  Also, I do not know why you mentioned it, since nobody else mentioned 'upstream' above.  I would not consider the 'upstream' module a beginner feature, so it's not very sporting to say "you should know this".  This is stackoverflow, where people come because they can't know everything.

Answer (score -2):

I had the same problem. Fixed it by using the local ip address of the docker host, instead of localhost.

So if the local ip address of your docker host in your LAN is 192.168.2.2:

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://192.168.2.2:3000;
  }
```

Of course this solution only works well if you have assigned a static ip to your docker host.