# Connecting from a docker container to the host?

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I'm on OSX using boot2docker. There's a redis server running on the OSX host on port 6379 and I'd like to access it from inside the container.

However:
`docker@boot2docker:~$ telnet 172.17.42.1 6379
telnet: can't connect to remote host (172.17.42.1): Connection refused`

**How do I expose the host port 6379 to the container?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810076/how-do-i-access-a-server-on-localhost-with-nginx-docker-container/27814576#27814576). You can either run your container with `--add-host` as mentioned or you might also be able to use your local Mac's dns name directly.

Comment: thanks. this helps. however the IP of my Mac keeps changing. How do I get the DNS name of my host Mac?

Comment: THANK YOU! Took me forever to find out a fix for this