# Cannot ping docker container IP from host machine

Tags: networking, docker

**What I am unable to do:**

Can ping the default docker network's gateway ip from the Ubuntu container, but cannot ping the container from the host machine, I have tried looking at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810076/how-do-i-access-a-server-on-localhost-with-nginx-docker-container/27814576#27814576) but this is something the other way round. I want to access my container from my host machine.

**What I have tried**

So I created a custom network using this:

```
docker network create --driver=bridge --subnet=192.168.0.1/24 --ip-range=192.168.0.130/24 --gateway=192.168.0.1 br0
```

This is the newly added network

```
$ docker network ls
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER
38bcca85e37a        bridge              bridge
202ace7d3e0c        none                null
512b3a6dc77f        host                host
d5f4b00e3281        br0                 bridge
```

and verified through the inspect command:

```
$ docker network inspect br0
[
    {
        "Name": "br0",
        "Id": "d5f4b00e3281c27e6d5879ac37463b6d8af728944dc7d3fbc23c25092020c7c7",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": {},
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "192.168.0.1/24",
                    "IPRange": "192.168.0.130/24",
                    "Gateway": "192.168.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Containers": {},
        "Options": {}
    }
]
```

and then ran my container using the following command:

```
docker run  -i -d --name=rc  --net br0 --ip 192.168.0.150 -v /var/log/restcomm/:/var/log/restcomm/ -e STATIC_ADDRESS="192.168.0.150" -e ENVCONFURL="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/RestComm/Restcomm-Docker/master/scripts/restcomm_env_locally.sh" -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 9990:9990 -p 5060:5060 -p 5061:5061 -p 5062:5062 -p 5063:5063 -p 5060:5060/udp -p 65000-65050:65000-65050/udp restcomm/restcomm:latest
```

then I logged on to the running container and ran the ifconfig command

```
$ docker exec -it a09a4c120999 bash
 root@8412c266634d:/# ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:42:c0:a8:00:96
          inet addr:192.168.0.150  Bcast:0.0.0.0  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::42:c0ff:fea8:96/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:508 (508.0 B)  TX bytes:508 (508.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:142 (142.0 B)  TX bytes:142 (142.0 B)



root@a09a4c120999:/# exit
```

The problem here is still that even the IP of this container is set to be **192.168.0.150** but it is still unable to ping the host machine whose IP is 192.168.0.115. Also the above command I have to run quickly, as you can see the container exits by itself, so i restart the container again and again to try and run a single command, if I try to login in again without restarting, it gives the following error:

```
$ docker exec -it e0783d69b96f bash
Error response from daemon: Container e0783d69b96f8e7ff4a17f76d0066b78c4b54a6817de7526a514f42a6af4640e is not running: Exited (1) 1 seconds ago
```

I verified this also by listing all the containers

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS               NAMES
e0783d69b96f        restcomm/restcomm:latest   "/sbin/my_init"          5 minutes ago       Exited (1) 4 minutes ago                           rc
```

I am running docker on windows 10 and followed these instructions from [here](http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-docker-quick-start-guide/)

Edit:
The container exits itself after I add this custom network, so probably there is something wrong in trying to add the network, but this command i have found in their official tutorial from [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/)

So there are 2 problems

1. Even though I can specify the IP I want I am still unable to ping to and from the container and host
2. The container exists itself after I add the custom network

EDIT:

Thanks to @VonC I fixed the second problem by adding the recommended switch, yes these two are not related

Comment: Problem 1 is certainly not helped by problem 2... To test your network, simply use `docker run -itd --name rc --net br0 busybox`. That won't exit.

Comment: oh yeah great now its not exiting, but I still cant ping to and from container and host, now the container IP is 192.168.0.2 and my host IP is 192.168.0.115

Comment: I never tried to ping a container from the actual host (Windows). I only pinged the Linux host (the boot2docker VM). And made sure my port were mapped on docker run to port in the Linux host.

Comment: My guess: The Windows host is not aware that there is a subnet that is reachable via the Linux VM. On Linux, I would try to run `route` to see the routing. According to [this post](http://superuser.com/questions/346347/on-windows-how-to-determine-route-for-ip-destination), `tracert 192.168.0.115` is the equivalent command for Windows.

Comment: @morxa your guess is very much correct, but what is the process of making the windows host aware of the subnet so that I can access the container from the host

Comment: did you tried to check VLANS?